# vim - aligning function arguments

Tags: python, vim, alignment

At work we follow this style convention for aligning python function arguments:

```
result = really_quite_extremely_long_funtion_name(first_argument,
                                                  second_argument)
```

I often find myself typing that second argument, realizing it's going to overflow 80 chars, hitting enter and then holding the spacebar until everything's aligned.  Is there a better way?

Comment: maybe use a pep8 plugin https://github.com/tell-k/vim-autopep8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a write up by Ygdrasil [here](http://orchistro.tistory.com/236) that will do what you need by editing `.vim/indent/python.vim`. Also this is answered previously [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492345/vim-how-to-indent-to-an-open-paren-or-bracket-when-hitting-enter)